# Lab Manager start WPF application under test

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have the following ALM infrastructure:

- TFS 2012
- Dev machine (VS 2012)
- Lab Manager with Controller and Agent
  Right now I am trying to build some Coded UI tests, in order to have some tests that I can "experiment" over multiple environments (Win7, Win8 ...)
  I have succesfully created a Coded UI Test and I can run it remotely using Lab Manager. My issue is the following:
  How can I run the WPF application under test before the test starts? Theoretically I should be able to find a ClickOnce app on my QA machine and the Coded UI Test should execute the ClickOnce and then run the Coded UI Tests.
  Is there any doc that explain this particular step of Test Automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open your application as part of your CodedUI test so that it happens automatically.

If you record the application open in Microsoft Test Manager and generate the test you will have it. 
If you are manually creating the CodedUI test in Visual Studio you will also need to record the open as part of each test.

The general flow for a CodedUI test is:

1) open application or browser
2) login if needed
3) navigate to the part of the application under test
4) [multiple test steps]
5) log out if needed
6) close the application

If you need to create distinct units for logging in or navigating that are common to multiple tests you can use Shared Steps in MTM

Comment: I was aware of that but probably I wasn't clear. I need to know how I can get a relative path on my tests to execute always the same app from the bin folder cause in my test OUT folder, the application under test is not deployed. I guess I will use a test settings file

Comment: If you are using Test Agents to run the tests then the happy path is that the application is deployed. If you use a Lab Build to deploy the application you will have an easier OOB time...